# Displaying list of files and subfolders in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application where it displays list of files within a directory and will pop up a message whenever there is a file in it that exceeds a certain file limit. But somehow I cannot make it to display the sub folders within that directory. How can I do this. Here is my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   private Timer timer;
    private int count;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    String[] s1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        count = 0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
        //Initialize Directory path
        s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE");
        //File Name, File Type, File size, create date
        for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                //Add Data Grid Columns with name
                dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
                dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
                dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");
            }
            //Get each file information
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
            FileSystemInfo f1 = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            //Get File name of each file name
            dr["File_Name"] = f1.Name;
            //Get File Type/Extension of each file 
            dr["File_Type"] = f1.Extension;
            //Get File Size of each file in KB format
            dr["File_Size"] = (f.Length / 1024).ToString();
            //Get file Create Date and Time 
            dr["Create_Date"] = f1.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            //Insert collected file details in Datatable
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            if ((f.Length / 1024) > 5000)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("" + f1.Name + " had reach its size limit.");
            }
            else
            { }

        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Finally Add DataTable into DataGridView
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        } 
    }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 60)
            {   
                count = 0;
                timer.Stop();
                Application.Restart();
            }
        }
        public string secondsToTime(int seconds)
        {
            int minutes = 0;
            int hours = 0;

            while (seconds >= 60)
            {
                minutes += 1;
                seconds -= 60;
            }
            while (minutes >= 60)
            {
                hours += 1;
                minutes -= 60;
            }

            string strHours = hours.ToString();
            string strMinutes = minutes.ToString();
            string strSeconds = seconds.ToString();

            if (strHours.Length < 2)
                strHours = "0" + strHours;
            if (strMinutes.Length < 2)
                strMinutes = "0" + strMinutes;
            if (strSeconds.Length < 2)
                strSeconds = "0" + strSeconds;

            return strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":" + strSeconds;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the following overload:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\FILE",
                   "*",
                   SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

this will look for all files in your directory (including subdirectories), which match the pattern passed in the second parameter.

Also, file names returned include full path to all files, so you can process them properly.

Comment: Thanks @suddnely_me!!
It works perfectly. But may I ask one thing, is it possible to display the folder in the datagridview which we can expand it and minimize on our own. Because if it display all of the files including the files in the sub folder in a single display, it will be quite messy.

Comment: Yes, yes, you can! (c) The best way here is to combine TreeView to show directory structure and DataGridView to show the contents of currently selected directory. It would be something like Windows Explorer, except you have a DataGridView instead if file listing.

Comment: BTW I guess I understand what you want to get, but AFAIK DataGridView can't do it solely.

Comment: I thought of that but I cannot find any reference so I thought that it is impossible. Glad to know that it is possible. Do you know how or do you have any useful link that can help.:)

Comment: What exactly is possible? Combining with TreeView or embedding it into DataGridView-like control?

Comment: just like you said, combining treeview with datagridview. Because at first, I wanna use treeview because it is more properly organized in displaying the list of files and sub folders. But I need to display the file size also, so I thought treeview is not so suitable.

Comment: Here is my proposal. First, you traverse desired directory tree and compose it to the TreeView. You can show it, hide-unhide subtrees etc. Then, you reference the treeView with a DataGridView, and handle TreeView onClick event in the following way: we clicked on the element - it represents a directory - we know it's full path - go to the DataGridView and display it's contents like i did before.

Comment: Timer clock simply traverse the TreeView and does the same for every directory, but instead of adding file info to the DataGridView it checks the file size and etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I see. So it's like when I click on a certain folder or files within the treeview, then it will show the details of the folder or files within the datagridview??

It worth a try. Thanks a lot man!!:)

Comment: P.S. This approach will have the same algorithmic complexity as using SearchOption.AllDirectories, but may yield in a better performance due to the framework features.

Comment: SearchOption.AllDirectories??
it won't be that complex would it??because I'm still quite new to programming especially in c# environment.

Comment: No, it will work O(N) where N is an overall files count. TreeView traverse will also work O(N). In fact, the will do the same stuff, except in the second case you'll have directory structure mappid inside your runtime.

Comment: I see. Ok I'll try it first and see how it goes. Thanks again @sddnely_me!!:D